# How to search for channels in a telegram through the library telethon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

At this moment I have a telegram client that reads all messages in a given channel.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, connection
import socks
import asyncio
client = TelegramClient('session4', api_id, api_hash, proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, str(proxy_ip), port),timeout=66)
client.start()
kanal='???'
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
dp = loop.run_until_complete(client.get_entity(kanal))
posts = loop.run_until_complete(client.get_messages(dp,limit=1000))
loop.close()
```

To automate the search for channels, I decided to get them through the channel search. Found a method

```
result = client(functions.contacts.SearchRequest(q='some',limit=100))
```

But he keeps returning an empty list. And I have doubts whether this is really that method? Or should I use something else?

Comment: You should clarify a bit more what you mean by "the search for channels". The `functions.contacts.SearchRequest` will (confusingly) perform a global search (including channels and contacts). If you want to search in your dialogs, you should use `iter_dialogs` or `get_dialogs` as seen in https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/client-reference.html#dialogs.

Comment: Did you import `functions and types` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_entity(). If you have the channel_id then you can do the following.

```
my_channel = client.get_entity(PeerChannel(some_id))
```

If you dont have the id but do have the name you can do this.

```
my_channel = client.get_entity('some')
```

You can find more information [here](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/497)

If you are looking to get all the channels then search you can start by getting all dialogs and then check the title for each chat if it matches your channel name

```
result = client.get_dialogs()

for chat in result:
  if chat.title == 'some':
    #do something
```

Comment: Please don't use `GetDialogsRequest`, there is no reason to. Use `client.get_dialogs()` or `client.iter_dialogs()`, which will fetch everything for you properly.

Comment: @Lonami the GetDialogsRequest was an alternative or just expansion of the solution but client.get_dialogs() seems more lean.